# Python: Generate a date time string that I can use in for MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, time, scrapy

How to do this:

```
from time import time
import datetime
current_time = time.strftime(r"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
l.add_value('time', current_time)
```

this will end up in an error:

> print time.strftime(r"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
>           exceptions.AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'strftime'

I found plenty of information - but it seems as if I either need to put it directly into an sql query or import anything else?
I'd like to have the time in a string first to pass it to my object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are importing a `time()` function from the `time` module. Instead, you need to import the module. Replace:

```
from time import time
```

with:

```
import time
```

Demo:

```
>>> from time import time
>>> current_time = time.strftime(r"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'strftime'

>>> import time
>>> current_time = time.strftime(r"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
>>> current_time
'13.05.2015 15:26:45'
```

---

As a side note, another option to have a time stamp attached to a scraped item in the database, would be to use [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) MySQL function and call it while inserting an item into the database in the pipeline.

Comment: I knew the `NOW()` but wanted to learn the Python side ;) Many thanks, that's working.